# How I can map the apache module .so (compiled code) with apache server

Tags: html, apache, module, rhel

I am trying to send the user input to the apache module.so. After passing the user input I getting a pop up to download the module or cancel.
I have loaded the module in apache server correctly using LoadModule module-name /path/to_module.so.
I dont know why I am getting this pop up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5zKl.png)